# $f(0)$ is integral over Fourier transform for Schwartz class

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $S$ denote the Schwartz class. Assume without proof that for every $f,g\in S$, we also have $\hat{f},\hat{g}\in S$, and $\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)\hat{g}(y)dy=\int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}(t)g(t)dt$. Show that if $f\in S$, then $f(0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}(t)dt$.

How to begin on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g$ be a flat, spread-out Gaussian function normalized to have the maximal value $1$: that is, $g(x)=\exp(-x^2/M^2)$. Its Fourier transform $\hat g$ is a sharply localized Gaussian, which you can find explicitly. The integral of $\hat g$ does not depend on $M$. In the equality 
$$\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)\hat{g}(y)dy= \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}(t)g(t)dt$$ 
The left side tends to a multiple of $f(0)$, while the right side tends to the integral of $\hat f$.

This is nothing but a special case of the [Fourier inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Proof).